# C# File.WriteAllText() method creating the file but not writing anything

Tags: c#, file-handling

public void SetVariables()        {

```
        textToWrite= installedVersion.ToString();
        log.Debug("Release version Update : " + textToWrite);

        File.WriteAllText(@".\test\test.txt", textToWrite);

    }
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are looking at the right file? You are extremely unlikely to have found a bug. 99.9% of cases you are just looking at a file different than the one you want. Use a physical path rather than a virtual one to make it easier to figure out.

Comment: Maybe textToWrite is empty or do you overwrite the File later in your code with an empty string?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you mean an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Comment: Remember that if this is a desktop application, when you run this code inside Visual Studio the path in which the application runs is BIN\DEBUG or BIN\RELEASE and giving the relative path you should look for your file starting from these folders

Comment: @Roman - log.Debug("Release version Update : " + textToWrite); This line priting correct Value. But when I am writing in file, file is getting created at relative path but the content of file is empty

Comment: @ManishKatepallewar maybe try another approach: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-write-to-a-file-with-csharp-stackoverflow-doesnt-get-it-right/

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Tried running with absolute path, still not working

Comment: Try deleting the file. And try it with File.Create and File.Append ...

Comment: @Roman var writer = File.CreateText(".\\test\\test.txt");
            writer.WriteLine(textToWrite);    ---- Still its not working. What's wrong in my code? Could you please help me?

Comment: have you tried to wrap it with try-catch? the output should be on yourProject/bin/debug/test/test.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var writer = File.AppendText("output.txt"))
        {
                var line = "Hello World!";
                writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

Try it like this. Look for the output file in your debug -folder if you are running the app in Visual Studio Debug Mode. If this works adjust the path.

If your textToWrite is too large, you can iterate over your lines:

```
using (var writer = File.AppendText("output.txt"))
{
   foreach (var line in lines)
   {
     writer.WriteLine(line);
   }
}
```

If it is way to large, read the example in the blog post, I commented to you

Comment: I am not running this through Visual Studio. Its running from my framework which is monitoring mentioned location and based on content of file its processing next instruction.  Tried running the above code still its running same issue. Nt sure its machine specific issue or something else

Comment: That could be the reason for your error. Maybe you can edit  post and describe your framework/ setup. It is possible that someone had a similar setup and error. What kind of .Net Framework are you using?

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\CDF

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\CDF\v4.0
    HttpNamespaceReservationInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NetTcpPortSharingInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NonHttpActivationInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    SMSvcHostPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    WMIInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1

Comment: Can you provide more information about your Code, because if textToWrite is not empty, and you created a file without an error, you deleted the file and it was created again und you found the newly created file in a dictionary, it can't be a rights problem, a path problem or a value problem.    Are you sure, the SetVariables function is called? Are you sure the file is not overwritten somewhere in the code when the method is called again with an empty string?